# Adding jQuery each generated inputs values together

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to concatenate the values of generated input fields together, so that it can be emailed off.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/NZy53/

Code here:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pass = 1;
    val = 0;
    jQuery('div.passport').each(function() {
        var index = "pass"+pass++;
        var passer = "<input class='pass' id="+'"'+index+'"'+" "+"/>";
        var passvalue = $(this).attr('value');
        jQuery(passer).appendTo('#pass');

        jQuery('#dup').click(function(){
        calc(passvalue);
        });
    });

    function calc(passvalue) {
        console.log(passvalue);
    };
});
```

Then the HTML:

```
<div id="pass"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<button id="dup">duplicate</button>
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pass = 1;
    val = 0;
    jQuery('div.passport').each(function() {
       var index = "pass"+pass++;
       var passer = "<input class='pass' id="+'"'+index+'"'+" "+"/>";
       var passvalue = $(this).attr('value');
       jQuery(passer).appendTo('#pass');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#dup', calc);

    function calc() {
      var passValue = 0;
      $('.pass').each(function(){ var v=parseFloat($(this).val()); if(v) passValue+=v});
      console.log(passValue);
    };
});​
```

[It works (open the console to see the sum of all fields)](http://jsfiddle.net/B2972/)

Main changes :

- using `on`, I could make it that the calc function is called only once when you click the button
- I parse the values of the fields and I don't add the value if it's `NaN`

Comment: works beautifully, but see need to "concatenate the values of generated input fields together" as you can read above... for its a passport number. Thanks so much so far :)

Comment: If you want to concatenate them as strings, use [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/F8wuN/).